# Function hide DIVs based on ACF Radio button input

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a created a Radio Button custom field, with three options:

- banner
- inline
- none

In my page template I have 2 divs containing the feature image, one is a banner, the other is inline sitting beneath the title, with the classes “banner-feature-image” and “inline-feature-image” respectively.

I would like to {display:none;} the class “inline-feature-image” when the ACF option “banner” is selected.

I would like to {display:none;} the class “banner-feature-image” when the ACF “inline” is selected.

And I would like to {display:none;} the both of the classes “banner-feature-image” and “inline-feature-image” when the ACF option “none” is selected.

I'm still early days into javascript and from what I have cobbled together from information online, I can’t seem to get the function working.

I have tried many variations on this.

```
    var image_location = get_field( "feature_image_location" );
    var inline_feature_image = document.getElementsByClassName('inline-feature-image');
    var banner_feature_image = document.getElementsByClassName('banner-feature-image');

    if( image_location == 'banner') {
      inline_feature_image.style.display = 'none !important';
    } 

    if( image_location == 'inline') {
      banner_feature_image.style.display = 'none !important' ;
    } 

    if( image_location == 'none') {
      banner_feature_image.style.display = 'none !important';
      inline_feature_image.style.display = 'none !important';
    }
```

Also some assistance with where to put it. I'm using the Code Snippets plugin for a few other things, but sometimes it work, and sometimes not ( assume because Code Snippets is for PHP?).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers Kristian

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well. A full example will be helpful in determining what you've tried so far and how it can be corrected.

Comment: Remember to choose the answer if it has been provided to you, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your assistance. I don't think I provided enough information in my original post. The ACF fields were located in the backend Edit Page, and the Banner image locations were located on the front end.

I think I also didn't fully grasp how ACF fields worked.

I was eventually able to figure it out by using wp_head to add styling based on the input of those fields

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'feature_image_script');
function feature_image_script() {
?>
<?php
$all_acf_fields = get_fields();
echo '<style>';
    foreach($all_acf_fields as $acf_field_slug => $acf_field_value) {
        if ($acf_field_value == 'banner'){
            echo 'body:not(.elementor-editor-active) .inline-feature-image { display: none; }';
        }
      if ($acf_field_value == 'inline'){
            echo 'body:not(.elementor-editor-active) .banner-feature-image { display: none; }';
        }
      if ($acf_field_value == 'none'){
            echo 'body:not(.elementor-editor-active) .banner-feature-image { display: none; } body:not(.elementor-editor-active) .inline-feature-image { display: none; }';

        }
    };
    unset($value);
  echo '</style>';
};
```

It may not be the cleanest implementation, but it achieved what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#radio_banner').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
      $( "#inline" ).css({"display":"none"});
      $( "#banner" ).css({"display":"block"}); 
    }
  });

  $('#radio_inline').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
      $( "#banner" ).css({"display":"none"}); 
      $( "#inline" ).css({"display":"block"});    
    }
  });

  $('#radio_none').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
      $( "#inline" ).css({"display":"none"});
      $( "#banner" ).css({"display":"none"}); 
    }
  });

  $('#radio_all').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
      $( "#inline" ).css({"display":"block"});
      $( "#banner" ).css({"display":"block"}); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
label[for="radio_banner"] {
  background-color: royalblue;
  width: auto;
}
#inline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
label[for="radio_inline"] {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="inline"></div>

<form id="my_form" action="">
  <input type="radio" name="display" id="radio_banner" value="banner"><label for="radio_banner"><span> Banner</span></label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="display" id="radio_inline" value="inline"><label for="radio_inline"> Inline</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="display" id="radio_none" value="none"><label for="radio_none"> None</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="display" id="radio_all" value="all"><label for="radio_all"> All</label>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want, you can replace `.css({"display":"none"})` with jQuery [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/), like in [this demo](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/pen/xeslL/), or you can choose to use pure JavaScript with `document.getElementById( 'elemtId' ).style.display = 'none';`

Here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/gL36m80w/) of the above code

Cheers